# Remove duplicate form select result

Tags: mysql, sql

## #edited

Ok. I will delete all role permissions and add them again.

Is it possible to combine all 4 queries into one?

---

I am creating a permission system.

Assumptions:

- Each user can have more than one role
- Each role can have more than one permission
- Permissions can also be assigned directly to the user (they have a higher priority than permissions for roles)

The priority of permissions is:

- role permission
- denial of role
- user permission
- denied to user

Denying the user has the highest priority

---

The matter in PHP is quite simple:

- I create an array with all permissions
- I am getting permissions for a role (order by access)
- I assign access, if it's denied, I overwrite access with denied
- I do the same for user permissions
- I assign access, if it's denied, I overwrite access with denied

This way I have the whole array with permissions for a specific user, e.g. $ user['permission']['delete_post'] // output: false || true

I need to do permission inspection now. This means which user has access to e.g. 'delete_post'

I have this database scructure:
[image: DB structure]
Here fiddle with database: [DB fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sjhDVF9goxcvkpBVoxAE5M/1?fbclid=IwAR1C9NaWSDKw_qPp9JjUHw1gFiPI0aBqTQ49O-lT1cYeRrLFJA4iGt64zoU)

I have problem with first query:

```
**Query #1**
    =============================================
        List of all roles related to permission with id 3   */
    SELECT DISTINCT role_id, access, permission_id FROM role_permissions WHERE permission_id=3 ORDER BY role_id, access DESC;

| role_id | access | permission_id |
| ------- | ------ | ------------- |
| 5       | 0      | 3             |
| 8       | 1      | 3             |
| 10      | 1      | 3             |
| 10      | 0      | 3             |
```

As expected I should get

```
| role_id | access | permission_id |
| ------- | ------ | ------------- |
| 8       | 1      | 3             |
```

I cant add `WHERE permission_id=3 AND access=1`, because i getting result: role_id=8 and role_id=10, but role_id=10 doesn't really have access.

Comment: So you actually want role_ids that don't have access=0. We often call that an exclusion join.

Comment: Why does your table have conflicting entries for `role_id = 10` ? Why it has access = 1 (allowed) and access = 0 (not allowed) entries simultaneously for the same permission ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya, in fact. When i edit permission for role, i can remove all with role_id  `DELETE FROM role_permissions WHERE role_id=:role_id` and then add anew. Thanks

Comment: @MichałB I think you are misunderstanding my question; how can a role have access and no access entries simultaneously for a particular permission; check the data that you have entered in the question please

Comment: Ok. Sorry, but i generate random data for this question, in my main database there will be no conflicting records.
Can i combine all queries to one?
I would like to have names of users who have access to e.g. permission with id 3

Comment: @MichałB I can give it a try but you need to minimize the data in your db fiddle here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sjhDVF9goxcvkpBVoxAE5M/1 Please cut it down to not more than 5-10 rows per table; so that testing can be done for the query. It is offcourse possible to do all this in just one query.

Comment: @Madhur, in every query i commented what i should get. 
For permission_id=3 in query#1 , a should get user_id in 4, 7, 13, 17, 48, 49 in query#3
Subqueries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to do all appropriate joins between various tables based on their relationships, and then do aggregation based filtering using `GROUP BY` with `HAVING` clause.

Following query will give you all the users who has access allowed for a given permission id (more explanation in comments inside the query below - there may be requirement of more fiddling with the logic; check and comment if needed):

**Query - [View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sjhDVF9goxcvkpBVoxAE5M/6)**

```
SELECT 
  u.user_id, 
  u.name 
FROM users AS u 
-- Left Join to get access (if defined for input permission id)
LEFT JOIN user_permissions AS up
  ON up.user_id = u.user_id 
     AND up.permission_id = 3 
-- Join to Roles; assuming every user has atleast one role
-- Change this to LEFT JOIN if it is possible that user can have NO role
JOIN user_roles AS ur 
  ON ur.user_id = u.user_id 
-- Left Join to get access defined for input permission id for roles
LEFT JOIN role_permissions AS rp 
  ON rp.role_id = ur.role_id 
     AND rp.permission_id = 3
GROUP BY u.user_id, u.name 
HAVING 
  -- first priority if user specific access allowed
  -- if data is sane then up.access will have same value 
  -- across all rows in a group for user
  MAX(up.access) = 1 

  OR 

  -- second priority is not have a single role with 
  -- denied permission AND 
  -- atleast one role exists with allowed permission
  ( NOT SUM(rp.access = 0) 
    AND 
    SUM(rp.access = 1)
  );
```

**Result**

```
| user_id | name             |
| ------- | ---------------- |
| 4       | Cyrus Gomez      |
| 7       | MacKensie Morton |
| 13      | Nadine Taylor    |
| 15      | Ezekiel Bonner   |
| 17      | Ciaran Turner    |
| 35      | Olga Dominguez   |
| 38      | Lucas Pierce     |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a WHERE condition as below-

```
SELECT DISTINCT role_id, access, permission_id 
FROM role_permissions 
WHERE permission_id=3 
AND role_id NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT role_id  
    FROM role_permissions
    WHERE access = 0
    AND permission_id=3  -- New condition added
)
ORDER BY role_id, access DESC;
```

Comment: Your query does not work: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sjhDVF9goxcvkpBVoxAE5M/2 Moreover, you are restricting all the roles which have access blocked for **ANY** permission id, which does not make any **practical** sense

Comment: I aid as per my understanding from the explanation. And you aid me to lose some reputation :( Anyway, check this adjusted fiddle...   https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sjhDVF9goxcvkpBVoxAE5M/4